# How do I organize JSON output after converting from CSV?

Tags: python, arrays, json, csv

I'm trying to convert a csv file to a json file to send to an api.  I'm having difficulty with structure of the json output that I've created.

```
import csv
import json

csvfile = open('User_List.csv', 'r')
jsonfile = open('user_list.json', 'w')    

csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
for row in reader:
    json.dump(row, jsonfile, indent = 4)
    jsonfile.write('\n')
```

My code currently outputs:

```
{
    "firstName": "Richard",
    "lastName": "Tyler",
    "email": "hallbeth@placeholder.email",
    "zip": "58570"
}
```

and I need it to read:

```
{
    "email": "hallbeth@placeholder.email",
    "Datafields": {"firstName": "Richard",
                   "lastName": "Tyler",
                   "zip": "58570"}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reorganize the data from each row so it's in the format you want before outputting it in JSON format:

```
import csv
import json

with open('User_List.csv', 'r', newline='') as csvfile, \
     open('user_list.json', 'w') as jsonfile:

    for row in csv.DictReader(csvfile):
        # Reorganize data into desired format.
        restructured = {
            'email': row['email'],
            'Datafields':
              {fieldname: value for (fieldname, value) in row.items()
                  if fieldname != 'email'}
        }
        json.dump(restructured, jsonfile, indent=4)
        jsonfile.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's call this `temp_dict`

```
temp_dict = {
    "firstName": "Richard",
    "lastName": "Tyler",
    "email": "hallbeth@placeholder.email",
    "zip": "58570"
}

new_dict = {
    "email" : temp_dict["email"],
    "Datafields" : { 
        "firstName": temp_dict["firstName"],
        "lastName": temp_dict["lastName"],    
        "zip": temp_dict["zip"]        
        }
```

You can simply create a new dictionary and assign values to it's key in this manner

Answer (score 0):

You could make a dict from your original `data` and use a comprehension for `"DataFields"`:

```
{'email': data['email'], 'Datafields' : {k:v for k,v in data.items() if k!='email'}}
```

See below for example

```
data =  data = {
    "firstName": "Richard",
    "lastName": "Tyler",
    "email": "hallbeth@placeholder.email",
    "zip": "58570"
}
organized = {
    'email': data.get('email'),
    'Datafields' : {k:v for k,v in data.items() if k!='email'}
}
print(organized)
{'email': 'hallbeth@placeholder.email', 'Datafields': {'firstName': 'Richard', 'lastName': 'Tyler', 'zip': '58570'}}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without defining the first 'data' section?  I provided one example from my json output, but have thousands of lines so unsure of how I'd use this method. Thanks!